# What is soft formating a Hard drive?

Tags: formatting

I found that there are two types of hard disk formatting, **Hard formatting and Soft formatting**, but was unable to get any information on this. Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you mean Quick format vs Full format?

Comment: @Moab I am not sure if the above given formatting methods have this name.

Comment: Never heard of soft and hard when it comes to formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Hard and Soft formatting are terms that are rather used in word processing.
Hard formatting deals with formatting a few pages of a document using tool bars icons,
keyboard shortcuts keys and menu bars; whereas Soft formatting deals with formatting
a large number of pages using styles.

Disks have rather the Quick and non-Quick (Normal) formatting.
Quick formats take a few seconds, whereas normal format can take several hours.
Both remove all files folders, but with the Normal method the hard disk is scanned
for bad sectors by rewriting all sectors, which also renews their magnetism.

Comment: I wonder if the question is referring to low level formatting in ancient mfm drives to lay down the tracks vs high level formatting done by the OS?

Comment: @davidgo Yes, I was looking for this.